# How to view document in top and bottom using Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I mean, side by side is supported in Notepad++. But if you viewing coding file, what you need is width, not height. side by side is great, but often times i need to view file using top and bottom approach. been searching for plugin but couldn't find any. anybody knows how? currently using 8.4.7 32 bit version. why 32 bit because some plugin i use dont support 64 bit version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With two panels open, right click in the dotted area (where the cursor changes to a two-headed arrow), select one of the "rotate" options. See [the Notepad++ user manual](https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/views/#move-clone) .